# Select a subset of excel Table given a value of given column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Table in excel like the following one:

```
col1 col2
A    1
B    0
A    2
B    2
B    3
```

I was not able to find a way to select a subset of the table like this one using an excel function.

```
col11 col22
B    0
B    2
B    3
```

based on the value `"B"` of column `col1` or just be able to select the `col22'` from the given subset.

I would like to have a solution that does not require to VBA nor array formula. I found on Internet the function [FILTER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759), but it is not available yet and [Structured References](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) does not have such functionality.

I would like to use for example the result `col22` as a column at another place of my spreadsheet. Other languages such as R, provide a function [subset](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/subset) that does this in a pretty simple way. In excel it is really easy to filter using the Excel interface (filter button), but I am not aware of a function that does something similar programatically.

Comment: Look into using pivot tables.  You may select a filter on `col1` to only the value `B`.  Then, what you would see would be the output table you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only thing I found on the internet was the [FILTER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function too.

I wanted to `vlookup` a subset of a table based on another column. My solution was to make another column that is the concatenation of the two. Then I used `vlookup` on this column.

I don't know what are you going to do with the subset table that you want to have. But you can do it in a different way as I did. May it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming col1 is A and col 2 is B and your result set's col1 and col2 are E and F respectively, try this formula in column C: `=IF(A2=$E$2,MAX($C$1:C1)+1,0)`

Now, in cell E2 (i left the first row for a header), i physically typed "B" to make this the input source and allowing for dynamic reporting. for as many cells below that as you wish, the following formula will only show the total number of "B"s that are in your input source: `=IF(ROW(A2)>MAX(C:C),"",E2)` Notice i did not fix the cells with $ as your following row depends on the former.

Cell F2 (the top of your col2 field for the result set) include: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,C:C,0))` and in G2 put: `=IF(E2="","",G1+1)` and copy both down as far as you have formulas in column E (or result set col1).

The reason for the IF statements is for formatting rather than displaying errors on failed lookups.

Comment: I am not sure to follow you. In my real example, I cannot add additional cells. In other languages like R there is [subset function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/subset). I am looking for something similar. I have a Table1 and I need to extract a subset of col2 with rows in col1 with value `B`. This sub-column is going to be the first column in another Table or in another portion of my spreadsheet.

Comment: is it safe to assume the user does not have access to the first data set? also, how is the item of interest being inputted by the user? are both data sets (date and result) excel tables?

Comment: this is just for having a clean excel. This is the purpose of using an Excel Table, and also to have more robust formulas.

Comment: sorry, its just very confusing as why to not just use a table in a separate spreadsheet with the data set being your first table (assuming the two must be separated). the user simply filters the table's col1 by value "B" and voila. Am i right to say this isn't to develop a working model but just as a proof of concept when comparing R to Excel?

Comment: This would be great, but it is not expected to be used by a user, that has to filter it. I need it already filtered using an expression, that does not require human action. In order languages such function exists, I am afraid in excel it is not possible so far.

Comment: ya sorry bud. maybe someone out there can help you out with this but it seems you're looking for some type of action out of Excel that has nothing to do with a spreadsheet. might be better off using R or Python for this puppy.

Answer (score 0):

Goal: extract a subset of the current sheet only when values in the first column match a value in the first column of another 'Sheet1':

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Add the formula above in the first cell of the first empty column, then sort Z-A this column and remove all "#N/A" rows, then re-order again A-Z the first column and remove this temporary column.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am looking for a solution for excel versions where the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) is not available yet. Check the functionality so you understand better the expected behavior. Your solution requires a manual intervention. i am building an excel to be used by others without forcing them to use the filter functionality from excel UI and instead to have a filter built-in using an excel formula